# Open Https URL in WebView without ssl certificate

Tags: ios, reactjs, ssl, react-native, native

I started to learn React Native and tried to made simple app. 
I've made server on Java and FE on React Native. And now i have a problem. WebView in React Native doesn't open the Https URL without ssl certificate. I made a self certificate but still NSURLErrorDomain -1202

Is it possible to turn off this notification? I can't make the trusted certificate, because i don't have a host and have to deploy my app only on localhost.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5VrN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>linkedin.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Add this in your Info.plist and in place of linkedin.com give your URL

Comment: Problem solved by using your code and WKWebView https://github.com/CRAlpha/react-native-wkwebview